# Test if in a R module

Tags: r, module, scope, conditional-statements

I'm exploring R modules https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modules/vignettes/modulesInR.html and I wondered if there is a way to check that a function is being run inside a module (mind, not just defined but running inside the module).

My use case is that I have a script that sometimes I source as a normal R script and sometimes as a module with `modules::use()`. I would like to wrap the package loading in this script to use `library` if called normally and `modules::import()` if run into the module.

Comment: Shameless plug: the ‘box’ package, which also implements a module system, makes this effortless: `if (is.null(box::name())) …`. [Check it out!](https://klmr.me/box/)

Comment: nice! great job!

Comment: does it also automatically install missing packages? that would be extra helpful!

Comment: No, it’s an active topic for consideration but I’m not convinced that regular R code *should* automatically install packages: package management and running code are separate tasks, and if the R package library is configured system-wide, user code doesn’t even have the necessary permissions to install packages. As far as I know, the Go programming language used to advocate automatic package installation and that turned out a mess, so they now advise against that (and instead rely on the `dep` tool for package management).

Comment: fair enough . A solution could be opt-in local package library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way in how `modules` override the library function:

```
environmentName(environment()) == "modules:root"
```

to be called in the environment where a function is defined, not in a function itself.